# Set UIImage as a background for 2D OpenGL ES on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, opengl-es, core-graphics

once again I'm asking for help after quite a bit of research.

I need to create a view where the user can place an image to the background and draw lines/dots(touch events) on top of it and then save the "sketch" by pressing save button.

So after research I decide to pick up [this](https://github.com/omeryavuz/glpaint) code and build the thing on top of it because it already does half of what I want(it does the drawing).

The sample I have is using OpenGL for drawing and basically I don't care if it is OpenGL or CoreGraphics as soon as it does it.

The problem I have is how to put an image as a background of EAGLView I have in this sample code. My research gave me only suggestions for OpenGL experienced developers but not the working code snippet/solution. 
If somebody can help me with this I would be very appreciate.

What I need is just a sample of how to put a UIImage to EAGLView background so then the user can draw(already have the code) on top of it and save the result.

Answer (score 3):

One usually doesn't mix OpenGL with ordinary `UI...` views. Also drawing a background image using OpenGL is trivial:

First you need to load the Image into a texture. In GLPaint a image file is loaded as brush-texture
https://github.com/omeryavuz/glpaint/blob/master/Classes/PaintingView.m function `initWithCoder`

To draw a background, the first thing you draw after framebuffer clear is a fullscreen quad with that texture. If you build upong GLPaint, then the projection and modelview matrix and the vertex array state are set properly already. So it boils down to

```
GLfloat vert[] = {0,0, frame.size.width,0, frame.size.width,frame.size.height, 0,frame.size.height};
GLfloat tex[] = {0,0, 1,0, 1,1, 0,1};
GLuint indexes[] = {0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0};

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, backgroundTexture);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);    

glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vert);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, tex);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 2, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indexes);
```

Comment: Ok, where do I get GL_QUADS and inside of initWithCoder method where it goes, I mean after I do things with brushImage/brushTexture(the 'if' statement) or before it? Thanks.

Comment: Like I told you, this is the first thing to do after clearing the framebuffer. So look for glClear(...) – line 306 in the linked source file.

Comment: ok, but in this case it is after cleaning up everything... Ok, will try but I still don't know where to get GL_QUADS. Sorry my OpenGL skills are equal to zero so I'm asking silly questions. Thanks.

Comment: @Alex Bush: You want the background picture interchangeable? Then the brushstrokes must be saved separately. OpenGL has no drawing persistency, it's basically just a collection of pens and brushes to draw on a canvas that is given to you by the operating system. So if you want to change the background you will have to redraw everything atop of it. GL_QUADS is a OpenGL token; you don't have to "get it". You'll have to learn OpenGL if you want to build upon GLPaint, there's no way to just "hook into it".

Comment: Yes, I know but I was hoping to just "hook into it" because I no need anything fancy. I already got the drawing code and I want perform this drawing on top of my own image and then save it(I have the saving code too). So this is why I'm asking about a working snipped of code. I have no intent/time to learn opengl right now. P.S. I understand that GL_QUADS is an OpenGL token as many others just my Xcode complains about it tells me it doesn't know what it is.

Comment: Well, that just means you have not added the OpenGL Framework properly.

Comment: My search gave me that GL_QUADS doesn't exist in OpenGL ES because it uses triangles. Still no luck with the code above :(

Answer (score 2):

In `PaintingView.m`, on line 89, set `eaglLayer.opaque = NO;`.

In your viewController, put a `UIImageView` or whatever behind the paintingView.

Note: This will probably decrese performance.

Note: It might not initially work; the OpenGL layer may overwrite itself with some sort of default background color before rendering a frame. EDIT: Line 304 in `PaintingView.m`: Try setting the color to `glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);`. I am not sure this works, and don't have time to test this. If it doesn't work, wait till Brad Larson comes around, sees your question, and answers it perfectly ;)